# How to show closed ports in NMap?

Tags: port, nmap

Any way to make NMap list the closed ports (I've tried -vvvv, etc.)? The filtered ones?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[`nmap -d -d`](http://nmap.org/book/man-output.html) can do this.

Comment: Great, this works exactly as expected!